# Get Value Of jTextPane Hyperlink

Tags: java, hyperlink

Hello there so I have a jTextPane in which I insert both normal and underlined text. What I am trying to do is when I click a hyperlink on the jTextPane to get the hyperlink String value. Do you have any idea how to do that? Thank you!
I need this for a chat. When someone uploads a file it would insert the following in the textpane: user uploaded file *file.txt*(as hyperlink). I just need to be able to grab the String value of the hyperlink when I click on it.

Comment: Take a look at [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#addHyperlinkListener-javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener-) on the `JEditorPane` class (superclass of `JTextPane`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really quick example of this in action:

```
public class Test {
    private JFrame frame;

    public Test() {
        // make frame
        frame = new JFrame("JTextPane test");
        frame.setSize(200,100);

        // create text pane
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

        // set up for HTML
        textPane.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
        // url of file
        String url = "file://path/to/somefile.txt";
        // disable editing
        textPane.setEditable(false);

        // put a hyperlink in the pane
        textPane.setText("<a href='" + url + "'>somefile.txt</a>");

        // add link listener
        textPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if ( e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED ) {
                    // if clicked, show the URL
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getURL(), "Link clicked!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        // add content
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPane);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    // run
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I already tried a different approach. Is it possible to grab the String value from the element variable?:    Element elem = jTextPane2.getStyledDocument().getCharacterElement(jTextPane2.viewToModel(e.getPoint()));
                  AttributeSet as = elem.getAttributes();
                  URLAction fla = (URLActionL)as.getAttribute(HYPERLINK_ATTRIBUTE);

Comment: yeah I know. I got another question. Why is't it working using the insertString() method? I want to append texts not replace everything everytime using setText()   this is what I followed: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2089990

Comment: @Niemand23 because the `StyledDocument` associated with the pane is not set up to properly handle the hyperlink. You could follow that example verbatim to configure it to behave as such, but an easier method might be to just use `textPane.setText(textPane.getText + "\nWhatever you want...")` which will effectively append the text. Even inserting the string like you can with the styled doc, you'd still need to scan to know where to insert the string.

Comment: Well the thing is that I also have icons in the textPane. BTW: I am using RMI. When an user uploads a file on the RMI server it would do following: jTextPane2.insertIcon(userIcon) then jTextPane2.getStyledDocument().insertString(jTextPane2.getDocument().getLength(), "\n User"+username+"uploaded ", style1); and then jTextPane2.getStyledDocument().insertString(jTextPane2.getDocument().getLength(), " "+remote.file_name(), style2);   style1-is for bold, and style 2 is for underlined texts(hyperlinks).

Comment: I already configured it so when I click it to download the last_file uploaded on the RMI but that's not goog enough for me. I want it to work with the older files too, but i just can't figure it out how to grab the String value

Comment: Is it possible to get the text based on theese offsets?:                                                 int start=elem.getStartOffset();
                  int end=elem.getEndOffset();

Comment: solved it :) :int offset=elem.getStartOffset();
                  int end=elem.getEndOffset();
                  int len=end-offset;
              
              System.out.println("\n start:"+offset);
              System.out.println("\n end:"+end);
              System.out.println(jTextPane2.getText(offset, len));

Comment: Now I got an annoying issue. After I click on the hyperlink the jfilechooser save dialog pops up, I click to save, it appends the text in the jTextPane"File was downloaded succesful to directory..:, but when I want to send a new message the icon get inserted in a wrong position in the textpane. Why would it do that? How could the mouse listener affect it?

Comment: This is beceause JTextPane must have some predefined mouse listener. Whenever a text gets double clicked it gets selected and if you use the insertIcon, the icon gets inserted in between the selected text. This makes no sense. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Figured it out myself again. I stored the last caret position into the motion listener: caretPos=jTextPane2.getStyledDocument().getLength(); and in the ClickListener I reupdated the caret position: jTextPane2.setCaretPosition(caretPos); It is so annoying when unexpected bugs come up.

Comment: One more issue: If I insert a large String into the jTextPane and then click on another tab of my jTabbedPane, the jTextPane automaticaly resizes. Another strange thing.

Comment: nevermind I got it again:   Dimension d=new Dimension();
        d.width=420;
        d.height=296;
        jTextPane2.setPreferredSize(d);

Comment: Ok this is really annoying. Now if I send a new message, the message gets inserted into the icon.

Comment: Once again I got it solved by right clicking on the textpane in the Designers View and unchecking the Autoresize-horizontal option. Gosh this is exhausting. Now I really hope it's bug-free.